# How do I remove this feature from my java perspective? The reset commands don't seem to work

Tags: java, eclipse

I accidentally hit a few keys on my keyboard and it popped up. I tried to reset my eclipse perspective but I'm not succeeding.

I can't post an image, because my reputation is low.
To give you an idea:

Under the name of the file
And above the first line of code
There is a header that goes as follows:

```
  (Project Name)->(Src file)->(Package)->(File Name)->(Method identifier)
```

Note: It only exists in my java perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you hit alt+shift+b

go through your toolbar, there should be an activated button with the title "toggle breadcrumb", if you hit it, your "header" will be hidden